# Obtener diffgr de un XML en PHP

Tags: php, xml

Tengo el siguiente XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<DataSet>
 <xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
 xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:choice maxOccurs="unbounded">
      <xs:element name="Table1">
        <xs:complexType>
          <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="GROUP_ID" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" />
          </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:choice>
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 </xs:schema>
 <diffgr:diffgram xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata" 
 xmlns:diffgr="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-diffgram-v1">
<NewDataSet xmlns="">
<Table1 diffgr:id="Table11" msdata:rowOrder="0" diffgr:hasChanges="inserted">
<GROUP_ID>NUM</GROUP_ID>
</Table1>
</NewDataSet>
</diffgr:diffgram>
</DataSet>
```

Necesito obtener el valor de diffgr:id, hasta el momento solo e logrado obtener el valor del nodo guardando este en un DOMDocument y luego obtengo el getElementByTagName('GROUP_ID') para mostrar sus valor, pero lo que necesito tambien es obtener el diffgr:id, ya lo intente con parentNode pero me regresa un error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo solvente de la siguiente forma:

```
$dom_result = new DOMDocument;
if ( !$dom_result->loadXML( $xml) )
throw new Exception( _( 'Error parsing response' ), 11 );

$nodo= $dom_result->getElementsByTagName('Table');

foreach($nodo as $id){
   echo $id->getAttribute('diffgr:id').'<br>';
}
```